# Resizing Image Canvas Size w/ JavaScript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, image-size

I'm trying to resize an image canvas size as I am pulling images from an API and saving them to my `images` directory but when they come through there are two types a default image which is `948 x 711` and an achieved image which is `948 x 340`.

So I'm looking for a method to get the achieved image size to match the default image size without changing the initial image resolution, so I assumed the best way would be to resize the canvas increasing the canvas top by `185` and again increasing the bottom by `186`.

So the canvas height would be `Achieved Height (340)` + To Top & Bottom `(Default Height (711)` `- Achieved Height (340) =  (371 / 2) = 185.5` Resulting in adding `185` to top and `186` to bottom.

**Default Image Example:**

[image]

**Achieved Image Example:**

[image]

**Example of Function:**

1. Go To Directory Get Image
2. Check Image Height
3. If Height != 711
4. Add 185 to Canvas Top
5. Add 186 to Canvas Bottom
6. Save and Overwrite Old Image

So if anyone knows of a way that I can turn my `Achieved` images into the same canvas size as the `Default` images that'd be increasingly helpful.

Thanks again guys.

Comment: When you say `Achieved`  can you elaborate more on this? I assume you're drawing the images on to a `canvas` and resizing? This should keep the aspect ratio if you're drawing the whole image.

Comment: No the API simply pulls them as either achieved or default, I'm not editing this at all. They just come through that way, which is why I'm trying to make them all the same after saving the images. So if image is `Achieved` then change canvas size to same as `Default` so I don't have any issues on my size when  loading the images as they will all appear the same.

Comment: **If you have any knowledge about canvas**, you can try loading the `Achieved` image on to a canvas. Make the canvas of the desired width and height, then start drawing from points (x, 185.5). Point `x` would be calculated as `canvas width - image width` / `2`. However, this would leave you with some dark spaces around the image, but you can hack around it. Let me see what you have tried first.

Comment: @officialpsoul I've added a function example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I haven't attempted anything yet as I didn't know how to approach this issue.

Comment: To clarify your question, may I ask what the extra whitespaces on the left and right are doing? What is the distance between the border and the image on all 4 sides?

Comment: The Padding should be Top: `185.5` Bottom: `185.5` Left: `108` Right: `108`

Comment: When you say `canvas` are you talking about the HTMLCanvasElement <canvas>? If so, why do you want to do this on front-end? If I read correctly your description of the problem, you are fetching images from an external resource, edit these images and then store them on your server, is that right? Then it's all a server-side job, there is no need for anything to be done on the front-end, this can be easily achieved with either [GD](https://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](https://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)